# Can greatest integer function (floor) be implemented with bitwise operators?

Tags: c, math, floating-point, bit-manipulation

The greatest integer function ⌊x⌋ is a function that gives the greatest integer less than or equal to a given real number x. It is also called floor.

The `<math.h>` header provides `floor`, which computes the largest integer value not greater than its floating-point argument.

I was wondering if one can implement this with the help of bitwise operators like `<<`, `>>`, or `~`.

Comment: What *is* a "greatest integer function"? What is it supposed to do? What is the actual problem that you have yourself?

Comment: The greatest integer of an unsigned integer type is just `-1` (unsigned integer types wrap around). The greatest integer of a signed integer type would be `(~0) - 1` if they wrapped around, but that's actually undefined behaviour for signed integers.

Comment: @Stef Are you sure about `(~0) - 1`? Wouldn't that be `-2`? If you have an unsigned integer of the same size, you could do `(~0) >> 1`, I guess.

Comment: @chtz Oops, you're completely right, `~0` is just `-1`.

Comment: Will that be the greatest `signed` or `unsigned` integer you'd like?

Comment: The highest value of a signed 2's compl integer of 32 bits would be `(int) ((1u << 31) - 1)`. The lowest is `(int)(1u << 31)`.

Comment: if it's signed integer then see https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#IntegerMinOrMax

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: They are asking for the floor function. Searching the C 2018 standard for “greatest integer” show exactly one result, in 3.21, defining ⌊x⌋. Searching the web for “greatest integer function” shows numerous results revealing this is a common name for it.

Comment: @Bob__: Because ⌊x⌋ is a function on real numbers and its analog in the C standard library, `floor`, is a floating-point function.

Comment: @FariyaAchhab I was going to say "Yes, you probably can, because a floating-point number is just bits, but it'd probably be a lot of work and a big nuisance."  But looking at a few examples, maybe it's not so bad.  In single precision, 1.234 is `3f9df3b6`, and 1.000 is `3f800000`.  123.456 is `42f6e979`, and 123.000 is `42f60000`.  There are some obvious patterns here.

Comment: @SteveSummit: Handling positive numbers is simple. Negative ones require more work. (`trunc` would be simple for both.)

Comment: `floor` cannot be computed with purely bitwise operators in a reasonable way. If the floating-point encoding is known and is typical, you can decode the exponent, determine the number of bits in the significand that represent values less than one, and clear those bits. That plus handling special cases (such as infinities and NaNs) will implement `floor` for positive numbers. For negative numbers, you need to do arithmetic to subtract one.

Answer (score 2):

`floor()` can certainly be implemented using only bit operations for the commonly used IEEE-754 binary floating-point formats, and likely for all binary floating-point formats. Because this approach results in a slow implementation, it likely has little or no practical relevance.

`floor()` rounds a floating-point operand to an integer using the rounding mode round-towards-negative-infinity. For positive operands, `floor()` behaves identically to `trunc()`, which also converts to an integer but uses the rounding mode round-towards-zero. Truncation basically removes the fractional bits from a floating-point operand.

The binary exponent in a IEEE-754 binary floating-point format tells us where in the significand (mantissa) pf the floating-point operand the fractional bits start, and we can simply mask them away. Very large numbers do not have any fractional bits and numbers less than 1 in magnitude have only fractional bits and thus result in zero. An exemplary implementation of `truncf()` for IEEE-754 `binary32` mapped to `float` looks as follows:

```c
float uint32_as_float (uint32_t a)
{
    float r;
    memcpy (&r, &a, sizeof r);
    return r;
}

uint32_t float_as_uint32 (float a)
{
    uint32_t r;
    memcpy (&r, &a, sizeof r);
    return r;
}

float my_truncf (float a) 
{ 
    const uint32_t FP32_EXPO_MASK = 0x7f800000u;
    const uint32_t FP32_ALL_ONES  = 0xffffffffu;
    const uint32_t FP32_MAX_EXPO  = 128;
    const uint32_t FP32_EXPO_BIAS = 127;
    const uint32_t FP32_NBRBITS_M1= 31;
    const uint32_t FP32_STORED_MANT_BITS = 23;
    uint32_t s, t, ur, ua =  float_as_uint32 (a); 

    s = ((ua & FP32_EXPO_MASK) >> FP32_STORED_MANT_BITS) - FP32_EXPO_BIAS; 
    t = (s > FP32_STORED_MANT_BITS) ? 
         ((s > FP32_MAX_EXPO) ? FP32_NBRBITS_M1 : 0) : 
         (FP32_STORED_MANT_BITS - s); 
    ur = ua & (FP32_ALL_ONES << t); 

    return uint32_as_float (ur);
}
```

For negative operands, `trunc()` differs from `floor()` when the operand has a non-zero fractional part. So we can construct `floor()` by first computing `trunc()`, and then conditionally subtracting 1 from the result. Obviously we want to accomplish this by bit-level manipulation rather than by a floating-point subtraction. We observe that if a floating-point operand is sufficiently large, subtracting 1 doesn't change the value. We further observe that if the *magnitude* of a negative floating-point operand is less than 1 but not zero, so in (-1, 0) the result of `floor()` is -1.

For the cases where we do need to subtract 1 the exponent of the floating point operand tells us where the least significant integer bit is located within the significand (mantissa). Subtracting 1 from the value means adding 1 to the magnitude and  IEEE-754 binary floating-point formats use a sign-magnitude representation. This leads to the following exemplary implementation of `floorf()` for IEEE-754 `binary32` mapped to `float`:

```c
float my_floorf (float a) 
{
    const uint32_t FP32_SIGN_MASK = 0x80000000u;
    const uint32_t FP32_EXPO_MASK = 0x7f800000u;
    const uint32_t FP32_MANT_MASK = 0x007fffffu;
    const uint32_t FP32_INT_BIT   = 0x00800000u;
    const uint32_t FP32_NEG_ONE   = 0xbf800000u;
    const uint32_t FP32_NEG_ZERO  = 0x80000000u;
    const uint32_t FP32_ALL_ONES  = 0xffffffffu;
    const uint32_t FP32_MAX_EXPO  = 128;
    const uint32_t FP32_EXPO_NBIAS= (uint32_t)(-127);
    const uint32_t FP32_NBRBITS_M1= 31;
    const uint32_t FP32_STORED_MANT_BITS = 23;
    uint32_t is_negative, gt_m1_ne_m0, has_fraction;
    uint32_t s, t, ur, ua =  float_as_uint32 (a); 

    s = ((ua & FP32_EXPO_MASK) >> FP32_STORED_MANT_BITS) + FP32_EXPO_NBIAS; 
    t = (s > FP32_STORED_MANT_BITS) ? 
         ((s > FP32_MAX_EXPO) ? FP32_NBRBITS_M1 : 0) : 
         (FP32_STORED_MANT_BITS - s); 
    ur = ua & (FP32_ALL_ONES << t); 

    is_negative = (ua & FP32_SIGN_MASK) >> FP32_NBRBITS_M1;
    gt_m1_ne_m0 = is_negative & (s > FP32_MAX_EXPO) & ~(ua == FP32_NEG_ZERO);
    has_fraction = ((FP32_STORED_MANT_BITS > s) & 
                    ~((ua & (FP32_MANT_MASK >> s)) == 0));

    ur = ((is_negative & has_fraction & ~gt_m1_ne_m0) ? (ur + (FP32_INT_BIT >> s)) : 
          ((gt_m1_ne_m0) ? FP32_NEG_ONE : 
           ur));

    return uint32_as_float (ur);
}
```

A few of the operations here are of arithmetic nature rather than bit-manipulation operations. We recall that, in twos complement arithmetic, a-b = a + ~b + 1. We also recall how a binary addition is composed from a sum-bit vector and a carry-bit vector, where the bits in the carry-bit vector have twice the weight of the bits in the sum-bit vector: r = sum + 2 * carry, where sum = a ^ b and carry = a & b. Lastly, we recall that unsigned comparisons are based on the carry-out of addition.

These fundamental facts allow us to construct helper functions `add32()`, `gtu32()`, and `eq32()` for addition, unsigned greater-than comparison, and equality comparison from bit-level operations. Note that comparison for (in-)equality *with zero* is a bit-level operation, as it simply requires ORing all the bits of the operand together. With the emulation functions in place, the implementation of `floorf()` above turns into the following:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

float uint32_as_float (uint32_t a)
{
    float r;
    memcpy (&r, &a, sizeof r);
    return r;
}

uint32_t float_as_uint32 (float a)
{
    uint32_t r;
    memcpy (&r, &a, sizeof r);
    return r;
}

uint32_t add32 (uint32_t a, uint32_t b)
{
    uint32_t sum, carry;
    carry = b;
    do {
        sum = a ^ carry;
        carry = (a & carry) << 1;
        a = sum;
    } while (carry != 0);
    return sum;
}

uint32_t gtu32 (uint32_t a, uint32_t b)
{
    uint32_t r, s;
    b = ~b;
    s = a ^ b;
    r = a & b;
    s = s >> 1;
    r = add32 (r, s);
    return r >> 31;
}

uint32_t eq32 (uint32_t a, uint32_t b)
{
    return (a ^ b) == 0;
}

float my_floorf_bit_ops_only (float a) 
{
    const uint32_t FP32_SIGN_MASK = 0x80000000u;
    const uint32_t FP32_EXPO_MASK = 0x7f800000u;
    const uint32_t FP32_MANT_MASK = 0x007fffffu;
    const uint32_t FP32_INT_BIT   = 0x00800000u;
    const uint32_t FP32_NEG_ONE   = 0xbf800000u;
    const uint32_t FP32_NEG_ZERO  = 0x80000000u;
    const uint32_t FP32_ALL_ONES  = 0xffffffffu;
    const uint32_t FP32_MAX_EXPO  = 128;
    const uint32_t FP32_EXPO_NBIAS= (uint32_t)(-127);
    const uint32_t FP32_NBRBITS_M1= 31;
    const uint32_t FP32_MANT_BITS = 24;
    const uint32_t FP32_STORED_MANT_BITS = 23;
    uint32_t is_negative, gt_m1_ne_m0, has_fraction;
    uint32_t s, t, ur, ua =  float_as_uint32 (a); 

    s = add32 ((ua & FP32_EXPO_MASK) >> FP32_STORED_MANT_BITS, FP32_EXPO_NBIAS);
    t = gtu32 (s, FP32_STORED_MANT_BITS) ? 
        (gtu32 (s, FP32_MAX_EXPO) ? FP32_NBRBITS_M1 : 0) : 
        add32 (FP32_MANT_BITS, ~s); 
    ur = ua & (FP32_ALL_ONES << t); 

    is_negative = (ua & FP32_SIGN_MASK) >> FP32_NBRBITS_M1;
    gt_m1_ne_m0 = is_negative & gtu32 (s, FP32_MAX_EXPO) & ~eq32 (ua, FP32_NEG_ZERO);
    has_fraction = (gtu32 (FP32_STORED_MANT_BITS, s) & 
                    ~((ua & (FP32_MANT_MASK >> s)) == 0));

    ur = ((is_negative & has_fraction & ~gt_m1_ne_m0) ? (add32 (ur, (FP32_INT_BIT >> s))) : 
          ((gt_m1_ne_m0) ? FP32_NEG_ONE : 
           ur));

    return uint32_as_float (ur);
}

int main (void)
{
    uint32_t uarg, ures, uref;
    float res, ref, arg;

    uarg = 0x00000000;
    do {
        arg = uint32_as_float (uarg);
        res = my_floorf_bit_ops_only (arg);
        ref = floorf (arg);
        ures = float_as_uint32 (res);
        uref = float_as_uint32 (ref);
        if (!((ures == uref) || (isnan (arg) && (ures == uarg)))) {
            printf ("ERR: arg=%08x res=%08x ref=%08x\n", uarg, ures, uref);
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
        uarg++;
    } while (uarg);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

In an alternative arrangement, adding a correction for negative inputs to `floor()` is performed ahead of the operation sequence that computes `trunc()`. This appears to result in a sizeable reduction in the overall number of operations:

```c
float my_floorf_alt (float a)
{
    const uint32_t FP32_SIGN_MASK = 0x80000000u;
    const uint32_t FP32_EXPO_MASK = 0x7f800000u;
    const uint32_t FP32_MANT_MASK = 0x007fffffu;
    const uint32_t FP32_NEG_ONE   = 0xbf800000u;
    const uint32_t FP32_NEG_ZERO  = 0x80000000u;
    const uint32_t FP32_POS_ZERO  = 0x00000000u;
    const uint32_t FP32_ALL_ONES  = 0xffffffffu;
    const uint32_t FP32_EXPO_NBIAS= (uint32_t)(-127);
    const uint32_t FP32_MAX_EXPO  = 128;
    const uint32_t FP32_NBRBITS_M1= 31;
    const uint32_t FP32_STORED_MANT_BITS = 23;
    uint32_t p0, p1, p2, s, mn, ur, ua =  float_as_uint32 (a);

    s = ((ua & FP32_EXPO_MASK) >> FP32_STORED_MANT_BITS) + FP32_EXPO_NBIAS;
    p0 = (ua & FP32_SIGN_MASK) >> FP32_NBRBITS_M1;
    p1 = s > FP32_STORED_MANT_BITS;
    p2 = s > FP32_MAX_EXPO;
    mn = p0 ? FP32_NEG_ONE : FP32_POS_ZERO;
    ur = p1 ? (p2 ? mn : ua) : (ua + (p0 ? (FP32_MANT_MASK >> s) : 0));
    s = p1 ? ((ua == FP32_NEG_ZERO) ? FP32_NBRBITS_M1 : 0) : (FP32_STORED_MANT_BITS - s);
    ur = ur & (FP32_ALL_ONES << s);

    return uint32_as_float (ur);
}
```

Comment: Sorry if I sound dumb but why are addresses like 0x80000000 and 0x007fffff being used? I know what 'u' means but I don't know why people use these numbers, is there a special reason to use them?

Comment: @FariyaAchhab I assigned self-descriptive names to all the "magic" constants. If you want to know about the specifics of those magic constants, you would want to study the details of the [IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) binary floating-point formats. The numbers are not addresses, they are unsigned 32-bit integers in hexadecimal notation, which is very practical when dealing with bit-level operations.

Answer (score 0):

This is sometimes possible, provided the representation of the fractional number is known and based on the binary numeration (which rules out DCB or fixed-point decimal numbers).

In the case of IEEE floats, you can extract the mantissa and exponent and based on these obtain the integer part by bitfield extraction and shifts (plus restoring the initial bit).

Needless to say, this will be complex, inefficient and little portable.

Comment: For positive numbers, there is never a need to deal with the leading bit of the significand. If the exponent is less than zero, you are going to return zero. Otherwise, you are going to clear some number (possibly zero) of bits in the significand field. The whole thing boils down to: From the exponent field, calculate `n`, how many bits to clear (31 if small, 1-23 if in the middle, 0 if large, infinity, or NaN), then change the bit string `b` encoding the `float` to `b >> n << n`.

Comment: What Eric Postpischil says. With shift counts adapted to floating-point type, of course. E.g. for IEEE-754 `binary32` mapped to `float`: `float floorf_positive (float a) { uint32_t s, ua =  float_as_uint32 (a); s = (ua >> 23) - 127; s = (s > 23) ? ((s > 128) ? 31 : 0) : (23 - s); return uint32_as_float (ua & (0x7fffffff << s)); }`.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: my answer relates to conversion to integer, not floor returning float.